# What is the purpose of action signals vs. queries in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

For some informations about gstreamer elements I have to emit a **query** like

`gst_element_query_position (data.playbin, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &current)`

(from [basic tutorial 4](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/time-management.html))

while for others I have to emit an **action signal** like

`g_signal_emit_by_name (data->playbin, "get-video-tags", i, &tags)`

(from [playback tutorial 1](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/playback/playbin-usage.html#page-description)).

What is the reason for that? Aren't both doing the same kind of thing, asking the element for some information and waiting for the answer (blocking/synchronously)? For me it seems that queries are exactly for that, as explained in the chapter "[Foundations](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/introduction/basics.html)" and the picture below.

But how do action signals fit into that picture? Are they a combination of event (for request) and message (for response) or also just queries? And most importantly: Why do they exist when there are already queries?

Thanks for your time and knowledge.

---

[image: Gstreamer Communication]

Comment: a very nice question. I suggest you to post it [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/)  on the official mailing list for Gstreamer developers.

Comment: one difference I see is that the queries are handled synchronously while signals are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vk_gst mentioned in the comment, queries are synchronous but signals (events) are not. The purpose of query is to get some information from pipeline whereas the purpose of event is to tell the pipeline to take some action for given condition/requirement. Example: You can query for bitrate of the stream. But you have to send signal (event) for playback seek.

In other words, query is for requesting some information and event is for notification. If an element sends a query, it expects some output apart from success/failure status. But if an element sends an event, it expects only success/failure status. How that event is processed is left to other element which has received it.

Comment: Thanks. So, a query is so to speak a "const" method, whereas an event is not?

Comment: There is no strict rule like query should be "const" and event should not be "const". It depends on the individual query and event. I have updated my answer with some more information.

Comment: Not very experienced with GStreamer but according to Jan Schmidt in 
https://youtu.be/ZphadMGufY8?t=4319 and the diagram provided, it seems as if signals and events are not the same thing and signals are synchronous.